# Is creating Bitmap over and over in loop is necessary?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, graphics, bitmap

is CreateDIBitmap everytime in WM_PAINT is necessary? I thought if I give it apointer to my buffer
it will be updated - but it looks it copies the data. The CreateDIBitmap - takes a lot of performance. CreateBitmap a little less.. The code below works - is it possible to put CreateDIBitmap outside of the loop (MY_BUFFER is updated every frame) - I tried to put it outside but I didn't see the content of MY_BUFFER anymore, just the DrawText with FPS..

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    HDC hdc_mem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbm_mem = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, &bitmapheader, CBM_INIT, &MY_BUFFER, &bitmapinfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);   // < --- killing performance !!!

    SelectObject(hdc_mem, hbm_mem);

                    // draw FPS
                        TCHAR tmp_fps_buff[16];
                        ZeroMemory(&tmp_fps_buff, sizeof(tmp_fps_buff));
                        swprintf_s(tmp_fps_buff, L"fps: %.3f", APP_fps);

                        SetTextColor(hdc_mem, RGB(255, 255, 255));
                        SetBkColor(hdc_mem, RGB(0, 0, 0));
                        SetBkMode(hdc_mem, OPAQUE);
                        DrawText(hdc_mem, tmp_fps_buff, -1, &APP_fps_rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_NOCLIP);
                    // ---

     BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, APP_requested_width, APP_requested_height, hdc_mem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

     DeleteObject(hbm_mem);
    DeleteDC(hdc_mem);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
break;
```

Comment: Yes, you can move the creation of the `HBITMAP` outside of `WM_PAINT`, if you use a different `HDC`, such as from the screen (`GetDC(0)`). Don't recreate the `HBITMAP` unless it actually needs to be changed (resized, pixel changes, etc), then you can `InvalidateRect()` your window to trigger a repaint. Have `WM_PAINT` simply `BitBlt()` the current `HBITMAP` as-is each time.

Comment: In addition to @Remy Lebeau's comment: when your buffer (the bits) changes ,you must call SetDBits( ... ) to update the current image.

Comment: @engf-010 Hi, thanks for answers.. my main problem is that I want to display content of MY_BUFFER  where I am changing its content every frame, when the CreateDIBitam is called only once outside the loop - I don't see the content of MY_BUFFER. Using SetDIBits works and its a "bit" faster than CreatingDIBitmap.. So, is that means that both CreateDIBitmap and SetDIBits copies the content of MY_BUFFER every frame?

Comment: I'm no expert on this ,but that's my understanding of it.